# How to Show time like iMessage iPhone app in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having trouble to display the time in UITableView while swipe like iMessage iPhone app. I have enabled the properties: **Shows Horizontal scrollers** and **Bounce Vertically**. But it is not working properly as iMessage app. It needs to shrike the UITableViewCell content and display the time.

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.isOpen && self.selectIndex.section == indexPath.section)
    {
        NujMessage *message = [self.sectionMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            int nujHeight = message.isNuj ?   15 : 0;
            int cellHeight = message.size.height + kMargin + nujHeight;


            if([message.moreMessages count] > 0)
            {
                return cellHeight > kNujMessageHeight ? cellHeight : kNujMessageHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                return cellHeight > kSectionHeaderHeight ? cellHeight : kSectionHeaderHeight ;
            }
        }
        else{

            int moreMsgCount = [message.moreMessages count];


            if(indexPath.row == 1 && message.size.height <= 70)
            {
                message = [message.moreMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
                [self setMakeSizeOfMessage:message];
            }
            else
                message = [message.moreMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

            int nujHeight = message.isNuj ?   15 : 0;
            int cellHeight = message.size.height + kMargin + nujHeight;

            if(moreMsgCount  == indexPath.row )
                cellHeight += 10;
            else
            {
                nujHeight = message.isNuj ?   15 : 0;
                cellHeight = message.size.height + kMargin + nujHeight;
            }
            return cellHeight;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NujMessage *message = [self.sectionMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        int nujHeight = message.isNuj ?   17 : 0;
        int cellHeight = message.size.height + kMargin + nujHeight + 10;


        if(indexPath.row == 0)
            return cellHeight> kSectionHeaderHeight ? cellHeight: kSectionHeaderHeight;
        else
            return cellHeight;
    }

    return kSectionHeaderHeight ;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NujMessage *message = [self.sectionMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    if (message.opened && self.selectIndex.section == indexPath.section && indexPath.row!=0) {
        static NSString *bubbleCellIdentifier = @"bubbleCell";

        NujBubbleTableViewCell *bubbleTableViewCell = (NujBubbleTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bubbleCellIdentifier];
        if(!bubbleTableViewCell)
        {
            bubbleTableViewCell = [[NujBubbleTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:bubbleCellIdentifier];
            bubbleTableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
            [bubbleTableViewCell setDelegate:self];
            [bubbleTableViewCell setFrame:tableView.frame];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap  = [[ UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(collapseMessages:)];
            doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
            [bubbleTableViewCell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
            [doubleTap release];

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizerMessage = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(performActionForMessage:)];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.bubbleImage addGestureRecognizer:recognizerMessage];
            [recognizerMessage release];
        }

        [bubbleTableViewCell setSelectIndex:indexPath];

        NujMessage *message = [self.sectionMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [bubbleTableViewCell setAllowEditing:message.editing];

        message = [message.moreMessages  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
        [bubbleTableViewCell setShowAvatar:NO];
        bubbleTableViewCell.moreMsg = NO;
        [bubbleTableViewCell selectCheckButton:message.selected];
        [bubbleTableViewCell setType:message.isFromMe];


        NSBubbleAlign align =   indexPath.section % 2 == 0 ? BubbleAlignMine : BubbleAlignSomeoneElse;
        [bubbleTableViewCell setupInternalViewWithMessage:message align:align];
        [bubbleTableViewCell didSelected:message.selected];

        if(isEditing)
        {
            [bubbleTableViewCell.contentView setAlpha: message.editing ? 1.0 : 0.5];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.avatarImage setAlpha: message.editing ? 1.0 : 0.5];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.labelName setAlpha: message.editing ? 1.0 : 0.5];
        }
        else
        {
            [bubbleTableViewCell.contentView setAlpha:1.0];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.avatarImage setAlpha:1.0 ];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.labelName setAlpha:1.0];
        }

        return bubbleTableViewCell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *bubbleCellIdentifier = @"sectionBubbleCell";

        NujBubbleTableViewCell *bubbleTableViewCell = (NujBubbleTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bubbleCellIdentifier];
        if(!bubbleTableViewCell)
        {
            bubbleTableViewCell = [[NujBubbleTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:bubbleCellIdentifier];
            bubbleTableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
            [bubbleTableViewCell setDelegate:self];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap  = [[ UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(collapseMessages:)];
            doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
            [bubbleTableViewCell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
            [doubleTap release];

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizerMessage = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(performActionForMessage:)];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.bubbleImage addGestureRecognizer:recognizerMessage];
            [recognizerMessage release];

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizerUser = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(performActionForUser:)];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.avatarImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.avatarImage addGestureRecognizer:recognizerUser];
            [recognizerUser release];
        }

        [bubbleTableViewCell setSelectIndex:indexPath];

        NujMessage *message = [self.sectionMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];


        bubbleTableViewCell.moreMsg =  message.moreMessagesCount  >  0 && !message.opened;
        [bubbleTableViewCell setShowAvatar:YES];
        [bubbleTableViewCell setAllowEditing:message.editing];
        [bubbleTableViewCell selectCheckButton:message.selected];
        [bubbleTableViewCell setName:message.buddy.displayName];
        [bubbleTableViewCell setType:message.isFromMe];


        [bubbleTableViewCell setupInternalViewWithMessage:message
                                                    align:indexPath.section % 2 == 0 ? BubbleAlignMine : BubbleAlignSomeoneElse
         ];
        [bubbleTableViewCell didSelected:message.selected];
        [bubbleTableViewCell hideCheckButton:message.editing];

        if(isEditing)
        {
            [bubbleTableViewCell.contentView setAlpha: message.editing ? 1.0 : 0.5];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.avatarImage setAlpha: message.editing ? 1.0 : 0.5];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.labelName setAlpha: message.editing ? 1.0 : 0.5];
        }
        else
        {
            [bubbleTableViewCell.contentView setAlpha:1.0];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.avatarImage setAlpha:1.0 ];
            [bubbleTableViewCell.labelName setAlpha:1.0];
        }

        return bubbleTableViewCell;
    }

}
```

With regards
Vadivelu

[image: iMessage]

Comment: post your cellforrowindexpath code for reference.

Comment: I have added my code here. Please review that.

Comment: @vadivelu check this link (https://github.com/shaps80/iMessageStyleReveal) it is good library.