# iMessage like time-showing when a message is swiped in TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing a way for the user to see a time-stamp for all messages when the any message is swiped to the left. Similar to the way iMessage does it.

[image: A simple label which will be revealed for all message when the user swipes on any message]
<sub>(source: [tekrevue.com](https://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ios8-messages-show-timestamp.jpg))</sub>

**Approach 1:**

I invested some time in researching on StackOverflow. The nearest I got an answer to my problem:

[How to Show time like iMessage iPhone app in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011928/how-to-show-time-like-imessage-iphone-app-in-uitableview)

This question was asked in 2014, is meant for Objective-C and the only answer suggests to implement a Pod. I am gonna be honest with you, I am not a big fan of Pods. They do slow down my project.

(To be fair, the GitHub mentioned in the comments of the linked question was updated to Swift)

**Approach 2:**

After the first Approach, I was thinking about using Cell-Actions / Swipe-able TableView Cells.

[image]

The idea was to replace the buttons by a single label. This would get the job done but it wouldn't "feel the same" as the users are used to from iMessage. Only one message would slide instead of all messages and when the user stops swiping, the cells/messages wouldn't animate back to their standard position.

Comment: Seems you should drag the whole table view, not individual cells.

Comment: Ohh okay. How would you do that?

Comment: Add a pan gesture recognizer to the table view and then handle the drag. You could add the time label to the cell, outside the view to the right and set the cell's and the table view's `clipsToBounds` to `false`