# How to Increase size of one side of a frame in swiftUI? (iMessage Drag to reveal time effect)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I have been trying to get this effect in SwiftUi, [iMessage like time-showing when a message is swiped in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470655/imessage-like-time-showing-when-a-message-is-swiped-in-tableview)

After searching and searching, I figured I would increase the width of my `scrollView`.
when I do this, it increases on both sides and offsets the recipients chat bubbles off screen to the left as well. Is there a way to only increase the width on one side of the `.frame()` of the `ScrollView` to hide just the time?

^Main Question^

Also, I tried offsetting the `HStack` off screen to the left (to hide time only, right element of `HStack`) which contains the time and the message bubble, although when I do this, the text is clipped and is not visible when I use `.gesture(DragGesture)`. Is there a better way I can achieve this in swiftUI?

Quick Skeleton of my actual code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
                ScrollView {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 20) { item in
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("(Message text)")
                                        .padding(30)
                                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                        .padding()
                                    
                                    Text("TI:ME ")
                                        .offset(x: 30)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            .offset(x: draggedOffset.width)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            self.draggedOffset = value.translation
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            self.draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
                        }
            )
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Message Text Field")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that due to the `ScrollView` in my project being rotated twice, I needed to use a negative x offset for it to work. Although still wondering about the frame.